# can I embed facebook single event on my website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I would like to embedded facebook single event in my website to invite user click attending button.
Is there any possible to do this ?

I have search facebook document but I can't call graph api to let user attend event.
And I don't want to embed fan page with tag "events" because this method would not show attend button and I would like to show single event.

Thanks.

Comment: Then you’re out of luck. Facebook does not offer any social plugin to directly embed a single event.

Comment: pretty bad. :/ Thanks for comment.